# How to integrate yii2-solr with mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, solr, yii2

I am pretty new to solr. I am using mongodb and yii2 for a while and quite familiar with concepts. Now I have this extension [yii2-extension-solr](https://github.com/dzun91/yii2-extension-solr/). This explains how to query from solr client withing yii2. But I want to know how to insert, update and delete the indexes on solr or data on solr, whenever changes made to my mongodb collections for instance. Please help me out.

Comment: Good to note that is actually a fork of https://github.com/Sammaye/yii2-solr

Comment: The first way would be to add updating and deleting from solr etc to your active record or a delta indexer that you build, the other way is to use a pre-made piece of software like https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20Solr

Comment: Great extensions though. neat and clean. Thanks for that! Can you elaborate the first way please?

Comment: I want the first way but i don't know how to do so.